# Mitel 5312, drop calls, and black boxes

Tags: mitel

So, i work a small law firm where we are using the Mitel 5312 phone, and on a daily basis users get drop calls and some even lose connection to the server.

When people notice that there call has been dropped, a blinking black box apears in top right corner of the lcd screen.

Does anyone else suffer from this? I have spent a number of hours trying to find a soluation over the internet, and have come up empty handed.

Any info regarding this issue would help.

Thank you!

Noobish of the Noobs

Comment: For a minute there I thought you where asking about phreaking tools.

Answer (score 1):

I get this a lot on our Mitel 5312s too -- in our case it has always been down to network disruption. 99% of our occurrences are on handsets on a separate site to the controller box, using teleworker via (dedicated) DSL links at each site, and whenever the DSL wigs out, I get dropped calls, silent calls, unresponsive handsets, strange screen artefacts, and eventually "PLEASE WAIT" on the screen of the device.

Assuming you're *not* using Teleworker and this is all over a local LAN, I would suggest trying to isolate the issue to particular handsets, and eliminating the possibility of flakey structured cabling, flakey ethernet cables, or flakey switching kit (if the phones aren't connected directly to the controller)